# Is any possible to add background picture to specify Eureka Form?

Tags: eureka-forms

I want add background to the form itself, but I can't figure out how to do it.

```
class ChallengeViewController: FormViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //how to add background picture to the form???
        form +++
            TextRow("title").cellSetup {cell,row in
                cell.textField.placeholder = "Task title"
            }
    }
}
```

How to work around it??? thanks :)

Comment: check this URL https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka/issues/834

Answer (score 0):

I know!

there are one pop name tableView...